# Comparing Integers Using "And" in If Statements

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, comparison, integer

This may sound dumb but I am stuck and I am having no luck searching on the internet what would be causing this to happen. I have a method that I want to check to make sure that both integers entered are both positive:

```
    Public Function BothPositive(ByVal num1 As Integer, ByVal num2 As Integer) As Boolean
    If (num1 And num2) > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Now if I were to enter some numbers in

> - BothPositive(1,1) = True
> - BothPositive(1,2) = False
> - BothPositive(-10, 10) = True

Why is this? What is going on with the order of operations in the comparison statement or what is the "And" trying to compare? I don't see why this wouldn't work.

**EDIT:** I understand how to work around but my question is *why* is this occuring? I want to know what is going on that is causing this.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done anything in VB, but it seems like the AND isn't returning what you expect it to. Why not just do `If (num1 > 0) And (num2 > 0) Then`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Vb.Net `And` represents a bitwise operator so what you're doing here is creating a value which is the bitwise `AND` of `num1` and `num2` and comparing that value to 0.  What you want to do is compare each value individually against 0.  try the following

```
If (num1 > 0) AndAlso (num2 > 0) Then
```

Note the use of `AndAlso` here instead of plain old `And`.  The `AndAlso` is a boolean operator vs. a bitwise and is also short circuiting.  You should almost always prefer it over `And`

Answer (score 2):

And is a boolean operation, and won't work on integers the way you are expecting (it is doing a bitwise or).  You have to write this as `If num1 >0 And num2 > 0 Then`...

Comment: But what is going on that would cause that? I know how to work around it but why would I not get a syntax error if I can't compare integers using And?

Comment: it is trying to interpret the integers as booleans, which vb.net does not stop you from doing, and I believe in vb.net every integer except 1 is interpreted as false.  Then the result of the And is interpreted as an integer (True = 1, 0 = False) and compared with 0; that's how you get the odd results you get.

Comment: In VB.NET, it will perform a bitwise And operation if the two values are numeric (so it won't be interpreting them as True and False). So in this case it will be returning an integer which is a bitwise And of the two input integers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function BothPositive(ByVal num1 As Integer, ByVal num2 As Integer) As Boolean    
 If (num1 > 0 AND num2 > 0) Then
  Return True
 Else
  Return False
 End If
End Function
```

Comment: I understand how to work around it but my question is why? I'd rather gain the understanding behind the problem than just "cover it up."

Comment: As antlersoft said, you are comparing if the value exists in yours. Not if it is greater than 0.

Comment: (num1 And num2) will return TRUE or FALSE.  (0 or 1)

Comment: If the numbers are the same it will return True. If the numbers are not the same it returns False. There is no syntax error. It is comparing the values and has nothing to do with being positive or negative.

Comment: Guess I'm not up to par on VB anymore. To me that should return a true or false(1/0) if they exist at all, no matter the number inside. I'll leave it up to antler to further explain, as I am outdated. Ignore what I've said in comments(although I'm pretty certain my code works).

Comment: You're code works it's just that I was looking for a reason. I found that it has to do with bitwise operations. If I compare 10 (Binary: 1010) and 5 (Binary: 0101), VB will compare the numers bit by bit and place a 1 if both binary representations have a 1 and a 0 if either one has a 0. So comparing 10 and 5 would get the result 0000 wich is not greater than 0 therefore, it would return false.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for sharing that. Good find, and probably something I should have known to look for, no matter what the language.